# Использование ROWID в запросах

Tags: sql, oracle

Интересует как я могу использовать ROWID в запросах?

Я нашел, что он применяется для быстрого удаление дубликатов записей в таблице:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);
```

Подскажите, как еще можно использовать это свойство? Или это больше не практическое, а теорическое свойство для понимания устройства БД?

Comment: По идее, использовать ROWID  в голом виде это тыкать пальцем в БД, не зная, куда именно. Правильно использовать поля структуры таблицы для работы с БД, иначе можно поломать её целостность вплоть до необходимости поднимать из бэкапа и выплачивать отступные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROWID - это физический адрес строки, поэтому доступ к строке по ее ROWID является [наиболее быстрым способом](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i8776).

ROWID уникален для каждой строки, поэтому его можно использовать в качестве суррогатного первичного ключа в различных запросах.
Oracle гарантирует, что пока строка существует ее ROWID не изменится.

Но, постоянно полагаться на ROWID в качестве первичного ключа опасно.
Во-первых, строка может перемещаться (delete+insert) в результате различных действий (импорт\экспорт, перемещение строки в секционированной таблице при изменении значения ее колонок входящих в ключ секционирования, перемещение таблицы (alter table move), сжатии таблицы (alter table shrink) и т.п.).

Во-вторых, после удаления строки ее ROWID может быть переприсвоен какой-либо новой строке.

Answer (score 2):

[ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-F6E0FBD2-983C-495D-9856-5E113A17FAF1) -- это псевдоколонка. Она имеет [одноимённый тип данных](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-4231B94A-97E9-4B59-91EB-E7B2D0DA438C), их не следует путать.
В SQL запросе эта псевдоколонка возвращает адрес записи, служащий для её локализации.

Основные применения значений псевдоколонки `ROWID`:

- Обеспечивают самый быстрый путь доступа к записи.
- Дают информацию о месте хранении записи (см. описание пакета [DBMS_ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ROWID.html#GUID-66872807-DA5F-4AD8-B447-69BCB258D69B))
- Они уникальны для каждой записи в таблице (см. пример в вопросе).

Для чего эти значения не следует использовать:

> You should not use ROWID as the primary key of a table.

Значения `ROWID` актуальны только в текущий момент времени, но нет гарантии их неизменности. Их не следует использовать для первичных ключей, или хранить в БД для каких то других целей.

Важное замечание об уникальности значений псевдоколонки `ROWID`:

> Usually, a rowid value uniquely identifies a row in the database. However, rows in different tables that are stored together in the same cluster can have the same rowid.

Они уникальны для таблицы, но не для БД в целом.

---

Практическое применение в SQL запросе относительно не частое.
В PL/SQL коде напротив - повседневно. Например, чтобы избежать повторного поиска записи в последующих статических запросах (быстрый доступ к уже найденной записи).

Так для явного указания в запросе:

```sql
create table t1 (id integer primary key, memo varchar2 (96));
insert into t1 select rownum, 'memo '||rownum from xmlTable ('1 to 9');

declare
    type ridarr is table of rowid;
    r ridarr; 
    cur sys_refcursor;
begin 
    open cur for select rowid from t1 where id in (3,6);
    fetch cur bulk collect into r;    
    forall ix in indices of r
        update t1 set memo = memo||'*'
        where rowid = r(ix);
end;
```

А так неявно в предикате `CURRENT OF`, который определяет текущую запись по `ROWID`:

```sql
declare
    m t1.memo%type; 
    cursor cur is 
    select memo from t1 where id in (3,6) for update;
begin 
    open cur;
    loop fetch cur into m; exit when cur%notfound;
        update t1 set memo = m||'#'
        where current of cur;
    end loop;    
end;
```

Comment: было бы здорово еще добавить [структуру ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998). Попытался найти доку, подобную [этой](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID) для актуальных версий Oracle, но не смог найти...

Comment: @MaxU Думаю, в рамках данного вопроса будет излишне. В первом предложении написал: не стоит путать 1) ROWID как псевдоколонку в результате запроса и 2) ROWID как тип данных. В вопросе речь идёт о первом.  Это всё равно что в вопросе о rownum  и order by, тут же  расказать о number  (как хранится, где используется), и только потому, что rownum имеет тип данных number.

Comment: не совсем согласен с вами. При практическом применении ROWID как псевдостолбца из него можно получить полезную информацию  - о принадлежности файлу (file id),  номер блока, номер объекта и т.д. и использовать полученные данные в PL/SQL

Comment: @MaxU Может быть вы и правы. Вы имеете ввиду этот пассаж из оф.док.: _They can show you how the rows in a table are stored_. Опустил его как маловажный, невозможно же всю документацию слово в слово перевести в рамках одного вопроса, на чём то надо и сэкономить ;)